# Matching the records in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a model `company`, which has `association`, has many `candidates`, and belongs to `company`.
And I have another model `key_skill`, which has `association`, has many `key_skills`, and belongs to `candidate`.
Another model is `candidate`, which belongs to `company`, and has many `key skills` association.

I am trying to get the `candidate` whose `key skills` are matched to the required `skill` and, it should search and get the `candidate` who belongs to the particular `company`.

How can I write a query in the model for this situation?

### These are the associations

company.rb

```
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base                                                                                    
   has_many :candidates                                                                                          
end
```

candidate.rb

```
class Candidate < ActiveRecord::Base                                                              
   belongs_to :company                                                                                                  
   has_many :key_skills, dependent: :destroy
   accepts_nested_attributes_for :key_skills, reject_if: :all_blank, 
   allow_destroy: true                                                                                             
end
```

key_skill.rb

```
class KeySkill < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :candidate
end
```

Comment: Sounds like something that can be done using scope, joins and merge.. https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/SpawnMethods/merge

Comment: Please add code of association

Answer (score 1):

I think your current association condition is like this:

```
class Company < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :candidates
end

class Candidate < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :company
  has_many :key_skills
end

class KeySkill < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :candidate
end
```

For example to fetch all candidates with key_skills with ids 1,2,3 run the following query

```
Candidate.joins(:company, :key_skills).where("key_skills.id in (?)", [1,2,3])
```

Comment: SELECT `candidates`.* FROM `candidates` INNER JOIN `key_skills` ON `key_skills`.`candidate_id` = `candidates`.`id` WHERE `candidates`.`company_id` = 1 AND (key_skills.id in (1,2,3))
 => #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Candidate id: 1, designation: "Senior Developer", candidates_available: "5", experience: "2", country_id: 1, city_id: 2, category_id: 1, created_at: "2017-11-27 06:23:14", updated_at: "2017-11-27 06:23:14", company_id: 1>]>                                     This is the output but i am not getting company name

Comment: for each candidate you can get company name like this, `candidate.company.name`

Comment: try this `Candidate.joins(:company, :key_skills).where("key_skills.id in (?)", [1,2,3]).pluck(:name, "companies.name")`

Comment: This is the query which i have in model, but company name is repeating how to avoid it.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     def self.find_candidates_on_key_skills
                                                                   matching_candidates_key_skills =      KeySkill.joins(:candidate).where("name like ?","%java%").order(:name)
end

Comment: what you meant by company name repeating? not clear.

Comment: if you just post the final expected result set structure, that will be great.

Comment: there is no way this query will fetch company name.

Comment: Key Skill: java ,Candidate id: 2 ,Company ID: 25294F, Company Name: ABC                                                                          
Key Skill: java,Candidate id: 3, Company ID: 25294F, Company Name: ABC                                                                                                                    In a same company i have two different candidates so how to avoid printing company name twice.

Comment: can you paste the rails terminal input and output exactly?

Comment: <% @find_candidates_on_key_skills.each do |m| %>
   <p>Key Skill: <%= m.name %></p>
   <p>Candidate id: <%= m.candidate_id %></p>
  <p>Company: <%= m.candidate.company.token %></p>
  <p>Company: <%= m.candidate.company.name %></p>
<% end %>                                                                                                     This is code for displaying the output above.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below:

I am assuming that `key_skills` table have a field `skill` and you want to perform search on it.

```
candidate = Candidate.includes(:company, :key_skills).where("key_skills.skill like ?", "%#{params[:skill]}%")
company = candidate.company
```